# How do I get the checked and unchecked values of a checkbox in angular

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes as shown below:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 md-padding"  *ngFor="let node of nodeList; let j=index;">
              <md-checkbox>
                <md-checkbox
                  class="md-h6 row md-padding--xs"
                  name="{{node.abc}}"
                  label="{{node.abc}}"
                  value="{{node.abc}}"
                  required="true"
                  htmlId="filter_label_{{j}}"
                  (click)="updatefilter(node.abc)"
                  [formControlName]="servers"
                  [(ngModel)]="node.selected">
                </md-checkbox>


              </md-checkbox-group>


            </div>
```

I have to check if the checbox is checked or unchecked. How do I proceed?

Comment: ```node.selected``` ?

Comment: `node.selected` should have a True/False value

Comment: `node.selected` is not working. I tried it. I am not able to get the selected value.

Comment: Can you update what node looks like?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara added. Can you please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the node itself doesn't have the selected property, first create one on node interface or node object.

Secondly add the `change` event on the checkbox whenever user clicks on the checkbox change will be called and you can toggle the value for `node.selected`.

In Html file:

```
 <md-checkbox
                  class="md-h6 row md-padding--xs"
                  name="{{node.FQDN}}"
                  label="{{node.FQDN}}"
                  value="{{node.FQDN}}"
                  required="true"
                  htmlId="filter_label_{{j}}"
                  (click)="updatefilter(node.FQDN); updateSelection(node)"
                  [(ngModel)]="node.selected">
                </md-checkbox>
```

In TS file:

```
public updateSelection(node) {
     // update the values to make them persistent
     node.selected = node.selected ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the `change` property doesn't seem to work. I tried to do a `console.log` on the `updateSelection` function , but doesn't display the `console.log`

Comment: I have removed `change` and added method to click check now.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, **never** use `[(ngModel)]`and `[formControlName]` in the same tag. Really is not allowed in Angular, so I don't know how can work the code

Comment: I just removed that. You can check [this](https://maxisam.github.io/2017/01/26/ngModel-in-FormGroup/), does it make any sense? You should not use both when you create forms in angular, however angular doesn't throw an error. One is recommended over the other when creating reactive or template driven form.